# Is there any way to disable the JSON ModelBinder in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders

In ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2, the default ModelBinder will automatically parse the request body if the `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`. Problem is, this leaves the `Request.InputStream` at the end of the stream. This means that if you try to read the input stream using your own code, you first have reset it back to the beginning:

```
// client sends HTTP request with Content-Type: application/json and a JSON
// string in the body

// requestBody is null because the stream is already at the end
var requestBody = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

// resets the position back to the beginning of the input stream
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
var requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Since I'm using `Json.NET` to do my serialization/deserialization, I'd like to disable the default ModelBinder from doing this extra parsing. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can put the following in Application_Start in your Global.asax:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(
            ValueProviderFactories.Factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().First());
```

This assumes there is only one of that type (which by default there is), but it can easily be changed to work if there is more than one.  I don't believe there is a cleaner way if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Is this an undocumented feature, or did I just miss something?

Comment: MVC includes a set of value providers factories by default.  With MVC3, they included the JsonValueProviderFactory as one of the defaults.  All the above code does is find it and remove it when the application starts.  Another way around it could have been not to have your ajax requests use the content type application/json, but I feel that removing the value provider factory is probably more correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't even aware there were provider factories for things like querystrings and routes. I'd assumed that the ModelBinder handled all of that.

Comment: Nope, my understanding is that the value providers essentially parse the request data, and the model binders then take the parsed data and fill the values of the models.

Comment: It would still be nice to disable this binder for a specific action instead of disabling it completely.

Comment: @Softlion Almost 6 years later, but I've added an answer that should allow you to disable the value provider for a specific action.

Answer (score 1):

I'm obviously pretty late in answering this, but I've developed a way to change the  `IValueProvider` for a specific action in MVC5. I haven't gone through the effort of seeing if this is possible in MVC3 since this question is old, but I assume it is somewhat similar.

Disclaimer: It's not pretty.

First, we create a new interface we can implement in an attribute to make action-specific configurations:

```
internal interface IActionConfigurator
{
    void Configure(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor);
}
```

Then, we create a custom `ControllerActionInvoker` (or `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` if you use `async`) to hook up our new interface:

```
internal sealed class CustomControllerActionInvoker : AsyncControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);
        var configurators = actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IActionConfigurator), true).Cast<IActionConfigurator>();
        foreach (var configurator in configurators)
            configurator.Configure(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
        return actionDescriptor;
    }
}
```

Now, we have to implement a custom `DefaultControllerFactory` to set `Controller.ActionInvoker`:

```
internal sealed class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var instance = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
        var controller = instance as Controller;
        if (controller != null)
            controller.ActionInvoker = new CustomControllerActionInvoker();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Finally, we set our custom controller factory as the default in the startup code:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));
```

and implement our `IActionConfigurator` interface in a custom attribute:

```
internal sealed class IgnoreJsonActionConfiguratorAttribute : Attribute, IActionConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        // Here we can configure action-specific stuff on the controller
        var factories = ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Where(f => !(f is JsonValueProviderFactory)).ToList();
        controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider = new ValueProviderFactoryCollection(factories).GetValueProvider(controllerContext);
    }
}
```

Since a new Controller instance is created on each request, we are able to set action-specific values on the controller to modify how MVC processes the action.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[IgnoreJsonActionConfigurator]
public async Task<ActionResult> Foo() { ... }
```